# What Is The Difference Between Type t() and Type t?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

```
class myClass {};
```

Simple question, what is the difference between `myClass t();` and `myClass t;`? If any?

Thanks.

Comment: Google "Most vexing parse". The first one is a function prototype, the second one creates an object of type `myClass`.

Comment: All the difference in the world. The first one is a function prototype and the second one is a variable declaration.